# Pass values / parameters to Azure Powershell function by HttpTrigger

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, sharepoint, azure-functions

I am trying to call an Azure function (PowerShell script) triggered by a HTTP url from C# code . I would like to pass some values/parameters to the Azure function from the code.

Ideally, I want to pass some user info to the Azure function and the function would run `Connect-PnPOnline` with the parameters. So far, the Webhook works but somehow I can't find a way to read data passed from the code. Or probably something went wrong when I tried to send data.

My C# code:

```
string theUrl = "https://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/xxxx?code=xxxx==";

var userInfo = new
{
    userId = $"ooooo",
    userPassword = $"xxxxxxxx"
};

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(theUrl));
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(theUrl, userInfo);
```

Powershell Script:

```
param (
    [string]$userId,
    [string]$userPassword
)
...
```

How can I read the object passed to the Azure function? Or is there better way to pass data to an Azure PowerShell function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With POST way, you could use this code to read parameter.

```
$requestBody = Get-Content $req -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$userId = $requestBody.userId
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your code but it had problem with binding the parameters. I kept having this error `[Error] : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
`. Seems it could't find `req`..? Do I need to modify the `param (...)`? Thanks

Comment: I got it working. I changed the way of passing parameters. `HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();`
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The C# code is correct to pass the parameters in the body of request method for **POST**.

Now in order to read the parameters in the Azure Function, by default all your parameters should be referenced by $Request.

```
# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
```

Read the Parameters as below:

```
# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$userId = $Request.Query.userId # Query based parameters ()
if (-not $userId) {$userId = $Request.Body.userId} # JSON Body (POST)

$userPassword = $Request.Query.userPassword # Query based parameters ()
if (-not $userPassword) {$userId = $Request.Body.userPassword} # JSON Body (POST)
```

Once you will have your parameters, you can make use of it in your PowerShell as per your requirement.

More Details on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-powershell)